# Find a set of $N$ numbers s.t. all combination of $N$ on $X$ with repetition of $Y \leq X$ sum up to a different value

Tags: co.combinatorics

I'm new to this forum I normally post on stackOverflow.

My question is related to combinatorics and subsets.

Here is an example:

$N=6$, $X=5$, $Y=5$; the set $\{0,1,6,31,108,366 \}$ has the following property:

however you take a subset in group of $5$ with repetition of at most $5$
the sum of that set will be unique among all others.

($\{ 31,31,31,31,31 \}$ , $\{ 0,1,31,108,108 \}$ are two random subset)

I've computed this set by brute force, now I'm asking if there are relationships between $N$, $X$, $Y$ (numbers, set size, repetition) and the distance between the resulting numbers in the set.

And I'd ask whether there's any trick to compute this set without burning a cpu.

Important: the set of numbers MUST be the one with the smallest numbers having that property, otherwise would be trivial to find one.

Starting from the previous set example you cannot decrease any of the number in the set $\{0,1,6,31,108,366 \}$ without breaking that property.

So lets call it "the minimum value set" with that property.
the trivial one where $N$=$6$ $X$=$5$ $Y$=$5$ can be found setting the first number of the set $N_{0}$=$0$ then $N_{i}$=$5*N_{i-1}+1$
giving $\{0,1,6,31,156,781 \}$.

Thanks

Comment: Since you're comparing sets with the same $N$, it's not clear what you mean by the smallest set of numbers. What makes one set smaller than another, if it's not the number of elements?

Comment: you are definitely right. I try to explain better, with smallest I mean the sum of them. so in the example {0,1,6,31,108,366} you can have a set with the same property only by incrementing the value of some of all of the numbers in the set. the most trivial set with that property would be {0,1,6,31,156,781} where the Nth number is 5*(N-1)+1.  btw I'm going to edit my question. thanks

Comment: In the case $X=Y$ the problem of characterizing sets with as few distinct subset sums as possible is a well-studied problem in additive combinatorics.  See, for example, Chapter 7 of these notes: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qdwqkgfnrkwr#/44219554/ .  This will at least familiarize you with some of the terminology and basic results.  I suspect, though, that your question is less interesting from that point of view, since one would expect a "random" set to maximize the number of distinct sums.